# How to extract only database name (Bucket name w.r.t. Couchbase) in java from the query

Tags: java, couchbase

I want to extract the Bucket name for the Couchbase DB here Test1 from the queries below, I want to write such a function which would extract only the database name, which ever query might be in Java, For example there are several queries I want to extract on Test1 i.e. bucket name.

```
CREATE INDEX adv_EmpName ON `Test1`(`EmpName`);

INSERT INTO `Test1` (KEY, VALUE) 
VALUES ("EmpId::4", { "EmpName": "test2", "EmpCompany" : "GS Lab4", "EmpCountry" : "India2"} ) RETURNING *;

SELECT EmpCountry from Test1;

DELETE FROM Test1  
WHERE EmpName = 'test4';

UPDATE `Test1` 
SET EmpComp = "San Francisco" 
WHERE EmpComp = "GS Lab" RETURNING *;

SELECT EmpName, EmpCompany 
FROM `Test1` 
WHERE EmpName = "test2" OR EmpCompany = "GS Lab4";

SELECT name, email 
FROM `Test1` 
WHERE name = "Monty Python" OR email = "monty@python.org";

SELECT * 
FROM `Test1` 
WHERE type = "airline" 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Test1 seems to be a table name, not a database name.

Comment: It is actually a bucket name for the Couchbase DB

Comment: If you want to do this from the Java SDK, you can use `bucket.name()`, is that what you're looking for? https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client/com/couchbase/client/java/Bucket.html

Comment: Are you trying to parse the N1QL query to determine which bucket it targets?